# how to use button click event to show another form over a network in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, network-programming

What i am trying to know is how a two different program/application connected over a same network that when a button from the other application is clicked the other application will function, such as a pop up message will show up when a button named Notify is clicked from the first application.

Comment: Use TcpListener and TcpClient.  Google for a VB.Net Chat example to find some code to start from.  You'll need to do a lot of reading and tinkering before you get this done.  There isn't anything "out of the box" that does this.  A communication protocol needs to be established so you can communicate in a reliable manner.  It's a pretty broad topic...

Comment: thank you so much sir, before posting this question i bumped into that so i think i'll start to it now. sorry for late rply this is my 1st question here.